# Celery command line error autodiscover_tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

When I'm trying to run celery 4.2 with Mac Mojave(10.14) and python 3.8. I'm getting following error. Please help me like what I'm doing wrong or what is error about.

Below is my code for celery app with Redis:

```
import celery

app = celery.Celery('tasks', broker='redis://')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task
def task1(ids):
    time.sleep(1)
    if not ids:
        return "ids can not be empty"
    print('Building dgraph through API', ids)
    funcsysc = funcsysc()
```

Command to run celery:

```
celery -A tasks -l info worker
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 275, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 416, in execute
    return cls(
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 238, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 252, in run
    worker = self.app.Worker(
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 114, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 108, in import_default_modules
    raise response
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 288, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 143, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 140, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 673, in _autodiscover_tasks
    return self._autodiscover_tasks_from_fixups(related_name)
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 682, in _autodiscover_tasks_from_fixups
    return self._autodiscover_tasks_from_names([
  File "/Users/tss/Desktop/tss/tssvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 684, in <listcomp>
    for pkg in fixup.autodiscover_tasks()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'autodiscover_tasks'
```

Comment: can you share the celery app creation code?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'd not recommend to use name `tasks` for the project. Rename if you could? Celery has some hardcode to autodiscover tasks in files/folders with name `tasks` by default and something might get wrong with this. Just a guess.